# Test Empty Component using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing my Login component which implements Microsoft authentication for login. I'm returning empty fragment from Login.js. How can I test this using React Testing library and jest?

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { msalInstance } from './authConfig';

export const Login = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    msalInstance
      .handleRedirectPromise()
      .then((tokenResponse) => {
        if (!tokenResponse) {
          const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
          if (accounts.length === 0) {
            // No user signed in
            msalInstance.loginRedirect();
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
```

Comment: RTL isn't really suited for components like this since there is no output. Instead you'll likely need to spy on `msalInstance` from the auth config. Since the component only makes a call, I would say testing it is sort of pointless. Test the function directly.

Comment: turn it into a hook and test it using https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution for this, is to get the root element of the rendered output and check for emptiness with the jsDom matcher function `toBeEmptyDOMElement`

```
test('test Login Component', () => {
  const { container } = render(<Login />);

  expect(container).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
});
```